# NODE RED -How to get payload_raw value from MQTT and save to MySql

Tags: mysql, mqtt, node-red

I am new to NODE RED and I am trying to get payload_raw value from MQTT and save it to MySql. 
This is reading from the sensor on MQTT:

```
rg186/devices/thingsnode/up {"app_id":"rg186","dev_id":"thingsnode","hardware_serial":"0004A30B001BDBBD","port":2,"counter":3792,"payload_raw":"DiwA2wcO","payload_fields":{"battery":3628,"event":"interval","light":219,"temperature":18.06},"metadata":{"time":"2020-01-20T09:24:01.609075061Z","frequency":868.5,"modulation":"LORA","data_rate":"SF7BW125","airtime":51456000,"coding_rate":"4/5","gateways":[{"gtw_id":"eui-c0ee40ffff296d5b","timestamp":3574037131,"time":"","channel":2,"rssi":-51,"snr":7.8,"rf_chain":1,"latitude":51.320107,"longitude":-0.55894303,"location_source":"registry"}]}}
```

I have connection with MySQl on NODE-RED and I have MQTT connection working as well and my question is how should I retrieve that payload_raw value and save to MySQL also would be good to know how to get payload_fields too.

I know how to insert to mysql.. What I need is to get that payload_raw value (DiwA2wcO) to string from MQTT: my function is:

```
var Data = msg.payload;
s = Data;
var payload_raw = s.payload_raw;
var t = s.metadata.time;
msg.topic = "INSERT INTO LoraTest (Bettery) VALUES ('"+payload_raw+"')"; 
msg.payload = [payload_raw]; return msg;
```

and topic in "mqtt in" node is -
 `rg186/devices/thingsnode/#`

I believe the topic in "mqtt in" is wrong and if there will be new reading on MQTT will it automatically use the function to save to database?

UPDATE:

I use TTN to sub device readings to mqtt and there I get it in the format like above, using this command:

`mosquitto_sub -h eu.thethings.network -t "+/devices/+/up" -u "rg186" -P "ttn-account-v2.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -v`

and I want NODE-RED to get the value of payload_raw.

What doesn't work:

I do not know how to set up correctly this (MQTT connection is ok but I do not know how to access data I am receiving in MQTT from NODE-RED): [image] and if this Flow and function are correct and allow to send the value of payload_raw to database right after ttn will send new reading to MQTT.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you already tried? The payload is a JSON string so you should be able to access any field in the usual way. You need to show us what you've tried and explain what didn't work and we will help you fix it.

Comment: OK, so the question is better, but you still haven't actually said what's not working. Are you not seeing the expected incoming messages, or are you getting messages but not in the format you expect?

Comment: The topic in the `mqtt-in` node doesn't match what you've stated in the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was trying different device, but over all which folder I should use as a topic? How I could specify where the sensor data is on MQTT?

Comment: Start with exactly the same as you used with mosquitto_pub `+/devices/+/up`

Comment: Still no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Put a debug node after the mqtt - then you can see the json in the "debug message", then from there you can see the path in the json for the raw payload.